# How to find input file type element under label tag

Tags: java, selenium

Unable to find input element for below HTML code.

**My code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(utils.driver, 30);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")));
element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"));
UploadFile().sendKeys("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\TestImage.png");
```

**Getting exception:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pageObjects.ProofPage.UploadFile(ProofPage.java:25)
```

**HTML code excerpt:**

```
<form name="proofCtrl.frmProof" ng-submit="proofCtrl.submitProof( $event )" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <div layout-margin="" class="layout-margin">
        <div class="column">
            <fp-s3-upload user-obj="proofCtrl.userObj" hide-upload-button="true" file-types="jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,gif,pdf,doc,docx,rtf" max-size-in-bytes="12000000" do-upload-all="proofCtrl.doUpload" on-get-url="proofCtrl.getUrl( fileObj )" on-preview-click="proofCtrl.showPreview( imgObj )" on-upload-error="proofCtrl.uploadError( error )" on-upload-warning="proofCtrl.uploadWarning( warning )" on-upload-all-start="proofCtrl.uploadAllStart()" on-upload-all-complete="proofCtrl.uploadAllComplete()" on-add-file="proofCtrl.onAddFile()" on-add-all="proofCtrl.addAll( filesObj, queueCount )" on-remove-file="proofCtrl.removeFile( filesObj, queueCount )" on-add-file-fail="proofCtrl.addFileFail( fileObj, filterObj )" on-item-upload-success="proofCtrl.itemUploadSuccess( fileObj )" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                <div class="fp-s3-upload-container layout-xs-column layout-sm-column layout-gt-sm-row layout-align-xs-stretch-stretch layout-align-sm-stretch-stretch layout-align-gt-sm-stretch-stretch flex-xs-grow flex-sm-grow flex-gt-sm-grow" flex-gt-sm="grow" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-align-gt-sm="stretch stretch" flex-sm="grow" layout-sm="column" layout-align-sm="stretch stretch" flex-xs="grow" layout-xs="column" layout-align-xs="stretch stretch">
                    <div class="fp-s3-upload-target layout-xs-row layout-sm-row layout-gt-sm-column layout-align-xs-stretch-stretch layout-align-sm-stretch-stretch layout-align-gt-sm-stretch-stretch flex-xs-grow flex-sm-grow flex-gt-sm-30" flex-gt-sm="30" layout-gt-sm="column" layout-align-gt-sm="stretch stretch" flex-sm="grow" layout-sm="row" layout-align-sm="stretch stretch" flex-xs="grow" layout-xs="row" layout-align-xs="stretch stretch">
                        <!-- <div ng-show="fpS3UploadCtrl.uploader.queue.length" class="ui red circular label floating ng-hide" ng-cloak>{{ fpS3UploadCtrl.uploader.queue.length }}</div> -->
                        <label ng-attr-for="{{ fpS3UploadCtrl.id }}" nv-file-drop="" nv-file-over="" uploader="fpS3UploadCtrl.uploader" over-class="drag-over" flex="grow" layout="row" layout-fill="" class="layout-fill layout-row flex-grow" for="fpop-14fa8c17018d">
                            <input nv-file-select="" uploader="fpS3UploadCtrl.uploader" ng-attr-id="{{ fpS3UploadCtrl.id }}" multiple="" id="fpop-14fa8c17018d" type="file">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fp-s3-upload>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code you shared a **`NullPointerException`**  was pretty much on the cards because-

When you do :

```
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")));
```

The `WebElement` is returned back. So first of all we don't need to search for the same element with `element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"));` any more. So effectively we can do:

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(utils.driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")));
```

Now, once the intended **`WebElement`** is returned we simply need to invoke **`sendKeys()`** method on the same **`WebElement`** **(** not through any other method e.g. **`UploadFile()`** **)** as follows :

```
element.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\TestImage.png");
```

So to get rid of **`NullPointerException`** your code will be :

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(utils.driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")));
element.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\TestImage.png");
```

Comment: now getting below error: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: input[type='file'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Using this code I'm able to upload my file successfully. Thank you guys I was stuck on this issue for more than 2 days. I used **driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'fpop-')]")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\TestImage.png");** and it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` returns a WebElement, so you can call `.sendKeys` directly on it.

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(utils.driver, 30);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"))).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\TestImage.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `NullPointerException` because something is going wrong in `UploadFile()`. I'm not sure what because you didn't post the code related to it. From the code you provided, I'm not sure why you need it anyway.

The code below should work.

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(utils.driver, 30);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"))).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\TestImage.png");
```

You wait for the visibility of the desired element and then `.sendKeys()` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, [TimeOutInSeconds]);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys([FileNameWithPath]);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated([ProgressBarLocator]));
```

Where

- `TimeOutInSeconds -> Maximum Timeout time to upload your file`
- `FileNameWithPath = "C:\\Users\\....\\Desktop\\TestImage.png"`
- `ProgressBarLocator -> Locator element indicating uploading continues`

Try to use longer timeout time instead of 30 sec only. It doesn't affect on uploading because as soon as uploading indicator is invisible it returns success.